# "How would J and Daenerys be related if R+L=J?"

Tags: game-of-thrones

In "Game of Thrones" Season 6 Episode 10, *The Winds of Winter*, we learn more about a character's heritage.

> If Jon Snow is the son of Lyanna Stark and Rhaegar Targaryen, as would seem to be strongly suggested;

What would his exact relation be to Daenerys Targaryen?

Comment: The last edit makes no sense at all. R+L=J is already confirmed, including a chart released by HBO after S06E10 and before S07 (see the accepted answer), so there is no need for a hypothetical; and what's the point of using J for Jon but then using Danaerys' full name?

Comment: @Flater Not for people who haven't watched the confirmation or are just starting reading the books, watching the show. Apparently, there's a meta policy that Spoilers are always spoilers. The title has to make a compromise which is meaningful enough and yet vague. R+L makes it clear for people who know what they are looking for that who is J. For those who don't, J could be anyone, Jaime, Jorah etc. If you have a better title in mind, feel free to edit.

Comment: @Flater Also if you are wondering about rationale of acts of a user, it's helpful to tag them in your comments so that they could explain it to you.

Comment: @Aegon: I didn't get the prompt to tag you (as you weren't in the comment history), does tagging work even if the username is not prompted? I assumed that it didn't but this may be misinterpretation on my part.

Comment: @Flater It works. As long as you type "at the rate Aegon", I will be notified.

Comment: @Flater this is an old question. I don't know who or why it was edited...

Comment: @Joshua Sorry my fault. I found it irksome that the tile was still very vague and meaningless after a year. So I made it explicit. However, it was later pointed out to me that Spoilers don't age, so I reverted it back. Then I thought current title was better, so I edited it into that

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> **Jon would be Daenerys' nephew.**

As Rhaegar Targaryen is Dany's older brother, both children of Aerys and Rhaella Targaryen, and

> Jon is Rhaegars' (possibly) illegitimate son (by Lyanna Stark), Dany is Jon's aunty.

Their family tree can be found towards the lower part of [this page](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/House_Targaryen).

**Update**

According to this [recently released character association chart](http://www.makinggameofthrones.com/production-diary/got-connections-ned-promise-tower-of-joy-infographic) HBO has confirmed that Jon is Lyanna and Rhaegars' son. Also, it does confirm that (in the show at least) Rhaegar abducted Lyanna, meaning that Jon is illegitimate.

[image]

**Update for Season 7:**

> It has been revealed that Jon is trueborn son of Rhaegar and Lyanna.
>  Rhaegar didn't abduct Lyanna, he loved her and she loved him back.
>  Rhaegar got his marriage to Elia Martell annulled and got married to
>  Lyanna instead. Jon's mother named him "Aegon Targaryen" on her death
>  bed.

Comment: Why stop there? They're actually aunt-nephew, cousins, second cousins, cousins *again* and second cousins *again*. This is due to Dany and Rhaegar being so severely inbred. In fact, Dany and Jon seem to share approximately 44% of their DNA; so genetically, they're basically siblings!!

Comment: Now explain their relations with their (future) kids.

Comment: The fact that the chart shows Rhaegar being Jon's father but also Rhaegar abducting Lyanna (which has now been proven to be false), means that there must have been a point in time where it was known that Rhaegar was Jon's father but his marriage to Lyanna wasn't yet revealed. You can infer from this that HBO intended for S06E10 to also confirm Rhaegar being the father, as this is the only time we are told something about Jon's parentage before the marriage itself is also revealed in S07E07 (or the "Regger" scene in S07E05, which again would confirm the marriage itself)

Answer (score 7):

According to [this Wiki Link](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Rhaegar_Targaryen):

> Rhaegar was the older brother of Viserys and Daenerys, though Daenerys
>   was born after he died.
>
>   Therefore, Daenerys would be Jon's aunt.